# JQuery Append não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera estou fazendo um carregamento sobre demanda uso um botão que ao usuário clicar nele carrega os dados de 2 em 2, esses dados vem do banco de dados, porem nesse código que postarei logo abaixo não funciona quando coloco os .

```
$(function(){

carregar(0, 2, "CarregarUsuario.php");

$("button.carregar-mais").click(function(evento){

    //desabilitando carregamento
    evento.preventDefault();

    var inicio = $("tbody tr").length;

    carregar(inicio, 2, "CarregarUsuario.php");
});

function carregar(inicio, maximo, url) {

    var dados = {inicio: inicio, maximo: maximo};

    $.post(url, dados, function (data) {

        for(i = 0; i < data.dados.length; i++) {

            $("tbody").append(
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + data.dados[i].CodigoUsuario + "</td>" + 
                "<td>" + data.dados[i].NomeUsuario + "</td>" + 
                "<td>" + data.dados[i].Email_Interno + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.dados[i].Senha + "</td>" +
                "</tr>"
            );
        }

        var conta = $("tbody tr").length;

        if(conta == data.resultadoQuantidade) {

            $("button.carregar-mais").hide();
        }
    },"json");
}
```

});

Nessa parte aqui se eu tirar o tr ai funciona mais não sei porque:

```
                "<td>" + data.dados[i].CodigoUsuario + "</td>" + 
                "<td>" + data.dados[i].NomeUsuario + "</td>" + 
                "<td>" + data.dados[i].Email_Interno + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + data.dados[i].Senha + "</td>"
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Pessoal logo abaixo esta a parte que faz conexão com o banco de dados, Acho que ficara mais claro como o código funciona:

```
<?php

include_once("ConexaoBancoDados.php");

$inicio = $_POST['inicio'];
$maximo = $_POST['maximo'];
// var_dump($_POST);
// $inicio = 1;
// $maximo = 10;

$resultUsuarioCont = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios");

$resultado["resultadoQuantidade"] = mysqli_num_rows($resultUsuarioCont);

$resultUsuario = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios LIMIT $inicio, $maximo");

if($resultado["resultadoQuantidade"] > 0) {

    while($linhaUsuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultUsuario)) {
        $resultadoDados[] = $linhaUsuario;
    }

    $resultado["dados"] = $resultadoDados;
}else {
    $resultado["dados"] = null;
    $resultado["resultadoQuantidade"];
}
// var_dump($resultado["dados"]);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Comment: Você poderia deixar assim: `"<tr><td>"` e `"</td></tr>"`. Qual o resultado se printar no console o texto que está sendo montado?

Comment: Imprimiu certinho:

Comment: imprimiu isso: <tr><td> </td></tr>

Comment: olha o que fiz no apped e não funcionou:]

Comment: $("tbody").append(
     '<tr><td> </td></tr>'
    );

Comment: Parece ter nenhum problema no seu código, veja: https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/2u38s0b2/ - provavelmente é em outro lugar ou outra coisa. Se puder fornecer um Fiddle mais completo para seu caso, nos ajuda.

Comment: Vou postar a parte que faz conexão com o banco de dados...

Comment: O que vem em `data.dados`?

Comment: Vou ver aqui...

Comment: Vem um array de Objeto com os dados que eu trago do banco de dados via Json.

Comment: Quando a tela é carregada clico no botão para trazer mais dados, mas ao debugar ai pude perceber que não esta entrando dentro do $.post();

Comment: Coloca um `console.log(data.dados[i]);` antes do `.append`, verifique se todos os objetos tem a mesma estrutura e se possuem dados.

Comment: Pois é coloco a tela para carregar automaticamente 2 objetos, ou seja duas linhas já vem carregas, só que quando clico no botão carregar mais ele nem entra no post, então quando clico no botão não entra no console.log(data.dados[i]), mas aparentemente os dados estão vindo corretor porque como disse já é carregado automaticamente 2 tr no cogido la em cima, exemplo: carregar(0, 2, "CarregarUsuario.php")

Comment: Melhor dizendo ele não entra no Post quando clico no botão, então ele não mostra o console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal consegui achar o problema acho que vou abrir uma nova pergunta, o problema está no php, json_encode esta retornando null, não sei porque, imprimi a consulta até antes de passar o json_encode e veio tudo certio, mas quando jogo os dados dentro dessa função ai retorna Null.

Answer (score 1):

Tente dar um id pra sua tabela e usar o código abaixo pra ver se funciona.

```
$("#idDaTabela tr:last").after(...);
```

**Update:**

Também parece haver um problema em como você está selecionando o botão. Coloque o id "button-carregar-mais" (veja que removi o ponto do id) no botão e chame assim:

```
$("#button-carregar-mais").on("click", function(evento){...});
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button-carregar-mais").on("click", function(evento) {
    $("#tabela tr:last").after("<tr><td>Nova Linha</td></tr>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-carregar-mais">
  Botão
</button>
<table id="tabela">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha Existente</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Vou tentar usar dessa forma !