# Uso do .append() ou .html() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Não estou conseguindo inserir html em um elemento.

JS

```
function carregaAgendamento() {
var url = "http://prestoexpress.com.br/vistoria/json.php";
$.getJSON(url, function(result) {
  console.log(result);
  $.each(result, function(i, field) {

    var id = field.id;
    var dataVistoriaAgenda = field.dataVistoriaAgenda;
    var tipoImovel = field.tipoImovel;
    var tipoVistoria = field.tipoVistoria;
    var codImovel = field.codImovel;

    $("#vistoria-agenda").append('<li><a href="#"><h2>'
      +codImovel+" "+dataVistoriaAgenda+'</h2><p>'
      +"Tipo: "+tipoVistoria+" Tipo Imóvel: "+tipoImovel+'</p></a></li>');
   });
 });
};
```

HTML

```
<body>
<p>Vistorias Agendadas</p>
<ul id="vistoria-agenda" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Ezequiel verifique se o seu retorno realmente possui alguma coisa, veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/175701/14262 a pergunta e bem similar, e o erro do rapaz era o retorno json

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio está retornando sim    [{"id":"1","dataVistoriaAgenda":"2017-02-06","dataVistoria":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","endereco":"Rua São Rafael, 34","tipoImovel":"Residencial","comentarios":"","tipoVistoria":"Saída","status":"Pendente","codImovel":"16524"}]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k9n3jLd3/2/ aparentemente seu código esta ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ezequiel, o site encontrava-se indisponível no momento da minha resposta, então criei um arquivo json.php para servir como teste e colei o seu json que você escreveu no comentário nele. Removi as interrogações(??) do meio do json pra não dar erro. Chamei a sua função e rodou de boa.

Exemplo de output:

> Vistorias Agendadas
>
> 16524 2017-02-06
>
> Tipo: Saída    Tipo Imóvel: Residencial

Segue o código utilizado para testar:

**json.php**

```
[{"id":"1","dataVistoriaAgenda":"2017-02-06","dataVistoria":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","endereco":"Rua São Rafael, 34","tipoImovel":"Residencial","comentarios":"","tipoVistoria":"Saída","status":"Pendente","codImovel":"16524"}]
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Teste Carrega Agendamento</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>
function carregaAgendamento() 
{
    //var url = "http://prestoexpress.com.br/vistoria/json.php";  // Site indisponível no momento

    var url='json.php'; // com json fake informado no comentário pra ver rodando
                        // Apenas removi umas "??" para não dar erro 

    $.getJSON(url, function(result) 
    {

      console.log(result);
      $.each(result, function(i, field) 
      {
            var id = field.id;
            var dataVistoriaAgenda = field.dataVistoriaAgenda;
            var tipoImovel = field.tipoImovel;
            var tipoVistoria = field.tipoVistoria;
            var codImovel = field.codImovel;

            $("#vistoria-agenda").append('<li><a href="#"><h2>' + codImovel + ' ' + dataVistoriaAgenda + '</h2><p>' +
            ' Tipo: ' + tipoVistoria + '<br>'+
            ' Tipo Imóvel: ' + tipoImovel + '</p></a></li>');
       });

    });

};  

window.onload=carregaAgendamento;
</script>   

</head>
<body>

    <p>Vistorias Agendadas</p>
    <ul id="vistoria-agenda" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">

    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consegui resolver usando o listvivew('refresh'); no final do append.. Pode ser algum conflito pois estou usando Jquery Mobile. obrigado